# Change the From Email Address or ReplyTo in Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form that we created on Google that my team uses to send Daily Reports. I copied a script to have an email sent with the contents of the form to a few different people in our company. The only issue is that each email comes from me instead of the user who submitted the form. How can I add this in to my script? Also, the email is captured when each form is submitted so maybe it can pull the email from the spreadsheet itself?

Here is the code:

```
function Initialize() {

  try {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers)
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("EmailGoogleFormData")
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
      .onFormSubmit().create();

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Please add this code in the Google Spreadsheet");
  }
}

function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {

  if (!e) {
    throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
  }

  try {

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {

      // You may replace this with another email address
      var to = "kevin@example.com";

      // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications
      var subject = "Daily Report";

      var key, entry,
        message = "",
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

      // Iterate through the Form Fields
      for (var keys in cols) {

        key = cols[keys];
        entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";

        // Only include form fields that are not blank
        if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
          message += key + ' :: ' + entry + "\n\n";
      }

      MailApp.sendEmail(to,subject, message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: what have you already tried to fix the issue?

Comment: Bryan, I have looked into GmailApp and apparently there is a From command there but I was not sure where to place the code. @BryanP

Answer (score 1):

MailApp does not allow you to change the sending address of the email, it will always send from the Google Account under which the script is executing.

The closest you could get (using MailApp), is to specify the Name and Reply-To values on the outgoing email. The email would still come from your address, but another name would be shown, and any replies could be directed to the appropriate user.

See the advanced parameters here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: Basically the same. GmailApp lets you access the inbox/threads and other Gmail features of the user account the script is executing under, while MailApp is only for sending mail.  I don't believe GmailApp provides a way to select or access another users inbox or send as other users.   If you must have the mail come from the user submitting the form, you could abandon the Google Form altogether, create the form in HTML, and serve it from doGet() in a script published to "execute as the user accessing the script".  See:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: setup - [Send mail from a different address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) then use...

`GmailApp.sendMail('toEmail', 'subject', 'plainBody', { from:'theOtherAddress@gmail.com', htmlBody:htmlBody }  );`

Specifying that `from` property in the options parameter will change who it's from.

The email will show up as coming from the other address "**via**" your main one.

Option 2: have each possible user authorize a script that monitors form submissions in a Sheet and sends out the notifications directly from their account with either MailApp or GmailApp.

Comment: the "from" option doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use a mail sent grid service like MailGun, which provide a HTTP API to let you send email more flexable.

but I'm not sure if it could let you "send email as anybody". if it couldn't, maybe you have to setup your own email server to do that.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html